# connect() and dup() and epoll() interactions for UDP descriptors

Tags: c, sockets, udp, epoll, dup2

Per the Linux man page on `connect()`, it is possible to invoke it on a UDP descriptor in order to default the peer addr/port to and from which datagrams are sent and received.  This also has a performance benefit in that a route lookup need only occur once instead of on every datagram sent.

My question is on how this interacts with `epoll()` when using a duplicate descriptor from `dup()`.  This may be Linux specific as well.

Say I have a single UDP listener and multiple UDP sessions, differentiated by peer addr/port, where each session has a duplicate of the listener socket descriptor and has called `connect()` on it.

Will `connect()` default the peer addr/port on the duplicate descriptor only, or will it pass through to the listener descriptor?  That is, can each duplicate descriptor be uniquely defaulted?

If so, will each duplicate descriptor behave uniquely for the purposes of EPOLLIN events?  That is, will an incoming datagram only trigger EPOLLIN on the duplicate descriptor associated with the peer addr/port?

I may need to just code this up and see, but wanted to ask first in the hopes of saving the effort.

---

The NetBSD man page for `dup()` specifically states...

*"...all object modes, settings, properties, and behavior other than the close-on-exec flag are shared between references.  This includes the setting of append mode, non-blocking I/O actions, asynchronous I/O operations in progress, socket options, and so forth."*

So I think I have my answer in that `connect()` on any duplicate descriptor will affect the listener descriptor and all of the other duplicate descriptors equally.

Comment: my guess is that calling `connect()` again on a `dup()`ed descriptor would also affect the original FD as well…  I'd also guess that `epoll()` wouldn't see any difference, and they'd all become readable at the same time when a packet is received

Comment: No need to dup(), for UDP you can just use `sendto()` on a single socketfd  [remember: UDP is connectionless]